# JavaFx Canvas Eraser Tool

Tags: java, javafx

I have a pretty embarrassingly simple problem with the Canvas in JavaFx.

I need to implement trivial paint/erase tools, and I've got the paint tool working, but I can't get the erase to work.

I've tried `clip()` and `clearRect()` but neither do anything in my case.. not sure what I am doing wrong there.

But, ideally, I would like the erase tool to work in the same manner as the paint tool (just with bigger stroke), not with the `clearRect()`-method. Can I achieve this with the blending modes or something?

Here's my current code:

```
canvas.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {

                if (erasing) {

                } else {
                    gfx.beginPath();
                    gfx.moveTo(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    gfx.stroke();
                }

                e.consume();
            }
        });

canvas.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                if (erasing) {

                } else {
                    gfx.lineTo(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    gfx.stroke();
                }
                e.consume();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you try painting with color.Transparent()?

Comment: Yep, I did, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. I got it working with clearRect() at least, the reason why clearRect() did not work, was that I had GaussianBlur effect added to the GraphicsContext.

Comment: The [oracle sample](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/canvas/jfxpub-canvas.htm#sthref11) uses clearRect() so I guess that's the best way.  You're right, the transparent doesn't seem to work, but the clearRect worked fine for me.